# Missing data when Marshalling map to JSON

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to marshal to JSON a struct `Foo` that has a `Values map[string]CellValue` property where `CellValue` is another struct.  For some reason, the resultant JSON does not contain the data held in the `CellValue` struct even though all the keys in the `Values` map **are** present.

Here's a [simple playground repro](https://play.golang.org/p/9Jpg1H0_RI) of the issue.

I'm new to Go, can anyone spot the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields of CellValue are unexported (start with a lowercase character). [Per the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) (emphasis mine), "Each **exported** struct field becomes a member of the object" - meaning unexported values are ignored when marshaling or unmarshaling.

Comment: Doh!  Absolutely right... this works: https://play.golang.org/p/-99s0wq8FK   I can't accept as answer just yet but will after 10 minutes